# How do I remove passphrase Authentification on FreeBSD ssh

Tags: ssh, security, freebsd

I am trying to set up a server that will just serve as a "Local Website", by local website I mean a http server that is not port forwarded. When ever I try to log in to it, it asks me for a passphrase. I know what a passphrase is but I don't want it to be needed to log in. I do not need anything super secure, and yes some people to strongly recommend it, and I understand, but my neighbors aren't hackers. What can I do to change it so I don't need a passphrase, all I want is to log in with a regular password. I know there is a config file in /etc/ssh/sshd_config but what settings do I change.

Comment: This is not at all a FreeBSD-specific question, you'd best remove the tag.

Answer (score 2):

Server is not asking for passpharse, server would ask for password.

Passphrase is part of your private key you are using for authentication. There are various methods how to remove passphrase from the key, for example using `ssh-keygen`:

```
ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
```

So for your case

```
ssh-keygen -p -P old_passphrase -N "" -f /path/to/your.key
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know the passphrase

Comment: so if you have different access to the machine, just create new key and copy it over the old one.

Comment: Alright I did that, know what